# swift: How to take access of one variable in another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have ViewController.swift and inside of this view controller i have

```
 let array = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("\(login)") as! NSArray
```

`let name = array[2]`

I want to take 3 element of array and use it in ProfileViewController.swift

What i should do?

Comment: `static` vars can help.

Comment: how static can help?

Comment: `static let array = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("\(login)") as! NSArray` and use it as `let name = YourClassName.array[2]`

Answer (score 2):

Use prepareForSegue method-

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "SegueToProfileView" {
        //Replace "SegueToProfileView" with your segue identifier
        let x = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileViewController
        x.arrayReceived = array

    }  
}
```

Inside ProfileViewController

```
var arrayReceived: [String]!
```

Whenever there is the segue is performed, arrayReceived will contain your array

```
let viewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileView") as ProdileViewController
viewController.arrayReceived = array
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't use storyboard)

Comment: If your array is already in NSUserDefaults, you can access that from your profileviewcontroller also

Comment: Even if you are using instantiateViewController, you can use the same logic

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know if it worked. I think it should though I generally use storyboard :-p

Answer (score 0):

class Eternal {

```
class func setObject(value: AnyObject!, forKey defaultName: String!) {
    let defaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(value, forKey:defaultName)
    defaults.synchronize()
}

class func objectForKey(defaultName: String!) -> AnyObject! {
    let defaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    return defaults.objectForKey(defaultName)
}
```

}

Usage

Eternal.setObject("Disconnect me. I’d rather be nothing", forKey:"Bishop")
Eternal.objectForKey("Bishop")